# jQuery prevAll for separate elements

Tags: jquery

How can I get the previous input value in the fiddle below? I get undefined unless they are in the same span.

```
<span>
<input type="text" value="48.00" >
</span>
<span>
<input type="text" value="44.00" >
</span>
$('input[type=text]').click(function () {
alert($(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prevAll` finds *siblings*. Those are not siblings. The `span`s they're in are, though, so:

```
var prevInput = $(this).closest('span').prevAll('span').find('input[type=text]');
```

Note that if you're using `prevAll`, you may end up with multiple `input` elements in the result. Calling `val` on the result will only give you the value of the first of them.